# Can information be thought without a physical realisation?

Tags: popper, materialism

Thoughts, memories, information, all are stored in some kind of physical representation. You might get down to a single quantum state of a electron to store one (quantum) bit.
Sir Popper tells us that products of the brain, like speech, music, math,... live in World 3, which is on top World 1, the material one.

Can information be thought without a physical realisation? Or is it always connected to a certain kind of materialism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you count energy, then everything is physical.  So you have just asked, "Can something exist without existing?"  The answer should be apparent.

Of course you can work at levels of abstraction where existence isn't relevant.  When I'm pondering what the integral of cos(x) is, it would be a distraction to note that states of ion channels and distributions of ions in my brain are responsible for such thoughts.  So *conceptually* information is not dependent on anything physical.  But all actual information is.

(In particular, [information is closely related to entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_in_thermodynamics_and_information_theory), which plays a role in Gibbs free energy.  You need some sort of substrate for entropy and/or information.  What the substrate is may not be the interesting part, but you can't do without it.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to form a thought, electrochemical impulses have to flow through a human brain. Or perhaps an animal brain. Animals don't have our rich language, but my experience is that they are certainly present in a sense that I interpret as consciousness. But that's for another time.

A "thought" is a physical process no less than the fusion explosions powering the sun.

As Rex Kerr indicates, even the so-called "abstract" objects such as mathematical entities do in fact have a physical underpinning. So ... is the development of mathematics contingent on the physical world after all? Do physics and information science determine what mathematics we can create? This would be a refutation of the popular belief that mathematics is independent of physics.

Comment: +1 what about the informational content of a thought compared to let's say random thoughts? Is there a difference in entropy/energy when I think of something "structured" like language?